# How do I write a dictionary info a text file in this format? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets' say I have a dictionary like this:

```
{itemone : 13, itemtwo : 243, itemthree : 47}
```

How would I turn it into a text file so it is in this format:

```
itemone 13
itemtwo 243
itemthree 47
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Th solution is clear: iterate through all items in the dictionary, and write key and value to the file. About which part of that task do you have a question?

Comment: You could convert a dict to a json file easily.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a file to write using a [**with** statement](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) and passing in `w+` as an argument:

```
d = {'itemone': 13, 'itemtwo': 243, 'itemthree': 47}
with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file_handle:
    for key, val in d.items():
        file_handle.write(f'{key} {val}\n')
```

**file.txt**:

```
itemone 13
itemtwo 243
itemthree 47
```